# how to change org-ellipsis foreground color?

Tags: org-mode, colors

Currently my org-ellipsis is " [+]"

```
(setq org-ellipsis "  [+]")
```

I want it to be slightly grey so that it will be less prominent but I don't want to change the foreground color of my headings.

I have gone through [emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OutlineMode#toc3) but still couldn't do it.[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the `org-` libraries have already been loaded ...

Type:  `M-x customize-face RET org-ellipsis RET`

To see a list of all faces for the `org-` library, type:  `M-x customize-group RET org-faces RET`

If the `org-` libraries have not yet been loaded, then evaluate `(require 'org`) using something like `M-x eval-expression` aka `M-:` before querying a particular face or group of faces ...

Comment: It worked thanks!